# Can't find general in Project Properties (Xamarin Android App Visual Studio)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

When I try to look for the target framework for my app, some sources on the internet said that i should look in the general section from the project.

But when I look over in the project properties, there's no general section?

Any help is massively appreciated!
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That `General` section is for Xamarin Studio / VS for Mac only. In `Visual Studio` it's under the `Application` tab which you can already see. It's the `Compile using Android version` option.

Comment: There's a doc on this here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework (Make sure that the doc is set to `Visual Studio` at the top right)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I need to figure out what the java error means that it gives instead of launching the app..

Comment: Open up a new question and I'm sure someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

That `General` section is for Xamarin Studio / VS for **Mac only**. In `Visual Studio` it's under the `Application` tab which you can already see. It's the `Compile using Android version` option.

There's a doc on this here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework

**Note:** Make sure that the doc is set to `Visual Studio` at the top right

Comment: I have set the Compile Using option to "Use Latest Platform (Android 5.1(Lollipop)). But when I load the project it says in the output: Found Xamarin.Android 7.0.1